# Lists in a list

Tags: python, list, shapefile, python-2.4

I am quite new to Python. I have a list containing some more lists, but only in two dimension (e.g. List[a][b]). Now for every value [a] I want to access a certain value [b] (10 in this case). For now it would be sufficent to just print every value List[a][10]. I tried:

```
for rec in List:
    print List[rec][10]
```

That gives me the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list". However if I just try "print List[0][10]" it gives me the value I want. In my for-Loop isn't rec an integer? How could I solve this problem?

Additional info: I am using Python 2.4.3 to be able to use the shapefile library that lets me access GIS data (my list).

Comment: If you `for` over a `List`, you get the **elements** (so the sublists), not their indices...

Comment: Don't call your list `List`. `list` is a reserved word in Python.

Comment: Since you are new to Python you really should be learning Python 3, unless you're forced to use Python 2 for some reason. Python 2 has various annoying quirks that have been fixed in Python 3, and Python 2 reaches its End Of Life in 2020. If you _do_ need to learn about Python 2 as well it's generally considered better to learn Python 3 first and then learn about the Python 2 differences latter, rather than doing it the other way around.

Comment: well the error itself is descriptive...you should have tried to print the "rec" so you would know that its not an integer. better to debug your error yourself. anyways use -> for rec in List:    print rec[10]

Comment: @Denziloe `list` is _not_ a reserved word (like `for`, `else`, etc), but it _is_ the name of a built-in type and it's not a good idea to shadow it by naming your own variable `list`. OTOH, `List` is ok as a name, but of course according to the PEP-0008 style guide normal variable names should be all lower case, Capitalised and CamelCase names should only be used for class names.

Comment: My 2 cents: Next time you face similar error/problem, try printing the element or its type, like `print rec` or `print type(rec)`, to get a better visibility.

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry yes, sloppy language. I should have said "special word" or something.

Comment: @Denziloe Fair enough. But the problem is that `list` isn't special (unlike an actual reserved word), which is why it silently lets you rebind the name to another object instead of raising `SyntaxError`. Sometimes it's useful to rebind the name of a Python built-in object, but most of the time it either causes no harm, or it leads to total chaos. :)

Comment: I don't know how you are using "special" but I am just using the normal English sense. It is special in the sense that it is a ubiquitous builtin that you almost certainly don't want to override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```
for rec in List:
    print rec[10]
```

or

```
for i range(len(List)):
    print List[i][10]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was surprisingly easy. Much appreciated!

Comment: `for i in range`

Comment: `for i in range(len(List)):`

Or better yet, replace this range with xrange

Answer (score 1):

```
for rec in List:
    print rec[10]
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

rec in your case is not an integer, it is the first item of list. For you to  use it as an integer you must add range in the for loop, like "for rec in range(0,len(List))"